# Show items from all sites in this site collection not returning any data in content query webpart

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, office365, content-query-web-part

I am using a content query webaprt to 'Show items from all sites in this site collection'. But it returning no data. Actually the site contain many data.

Then I have tried using 'Show items from the following list:' and mention a specific list. That returns all the data on that specific list. But I need data from many list.

Please advise!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display all the items from a "Custom List" then select the "List Type" as "Custom List" under the "Query" section.

[image]

After that remove the contents from the "Link" field under "Presentation > Fields to display" section.

[image]

Save the webpart and you would be able to view all the items from all the custom lists.